# How to make x-axis mirror work on newly created bones? (2.79)

Tags: armature, bones, transforms

I'm rigging a model from scratch, but I'm not sure how to make it detect two bones as the "same" one, so that when I transform one bone (in edit mode) it transforms both. How do I make it so that it sees the bones that way? Is there a specific way in which I need to create the bones, or is there a shortcut I can use, or something else?

Example of it not working:

[image: An armature is visible. A bone on the left is transformed but an identical one on the right is not transformed along with it. The same is done on the other side and the same happens.]

Comment: I think it was naming the left side *.L and the right side *.R

Comment: @HenrikD Yes, that was it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the Mirror Option to know what it should mirror, you need to name the bones according to some guidelines on the wiki (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/editing/naming.html). There are also Tools to for example flip the side in the name or mirror bones and their names. You find them in the Armature Menu > Names.